# Coloring text dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, dynamic

I have a webiste, that takes an input string, and marks part of it with a color,
according to a dropDownList.

this is done with replacing a regex and a generated  tag with style.

Is it better practice to surround it with a  with a specific class 
and set the style of that class in the css (again it has to change according to the dropdown)

meaning every time the "mark" button is matched, the script will change a rule in the CSS.

is it possible to do so, and how exactly.
I couldn't find any way to access a css rule by its name.

Comment: How many colours are required? Or are the colours specified dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

```
    <div id="dv">sample text</div>
    <input type="button" onclick="changeColor('#959562');">
    <script language="javascript">
function changeColor(color)
    {
jQuery('#dv').css('color',color);
    }
        </script>
```

use this type of code you can change color dynamically by using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

If the number of colors is not known ahead of time you can simply do

```
<span style="background-color:#424242">text </span>
```

in your regular expression. Replace the number with color of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't change the CSS rule, have several CSS rules that correspond to the different colours.

The event handler for the drop down should then update the class attribute of the input string.